# Identify which nth child of tr a specific td is in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

With reference to the table example below, how do I, in `jQuery`, identify the descendant number (below 3) is to the row of the column?

```
$(".colclass").click(function (e) {
  //get td descendant number to tr, ie 3 in this case
});

<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="colclass"></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.index` to get the index of the target as a child to the parent element (i.e., `tr` in this case):

```js
$(".colclass").click(function (e) {
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="colclass">3</td>
      <td>4</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```